# how to show div elements in one line

Tags: css, html

I have a problem in my div elements I can not show them in one line:

```
<div>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>hellow world</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <ul>
  <li>hi world</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

the table shown above the the ul and I want the tow elements to shown in one line next to each other.
I tried to use:

```
div
{
   display:inline;
}
```

or :

```
div
{
   display:block;
}
```

But it did not work . any body can help me on this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to show the `table` and the `ul` side by side, those are the two elements you should target, not the container they happen to be in.

If they are the same height, simply writing

```
table {float:left; margin-right:40px}
```

will do the trick. (You will need the margin, because lists also work with margins to show the bullets, and the bullet would end up inside the table if you didn't provide for that.)

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/MQTNk/)

If the table is higher, you will also have to clear the float afterwards, else subsequent content may also end up to the right of the table:

```
div::after {content:''; display:block; clear:both}
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/c3sda/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Float your content:

```
div
{
   float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `display:inline-block`, but the key is making sure you apply it to the correct elements...

```
table, ul
{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/DumA8/)

Answer (score 0):

you can just use `table,ul{display: inline-block;}` [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V3bSz/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <div>
    <table style="float: left;">
        <tr>
            <td width="100">
                hellow world
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>   <ul>
        <li>hi world</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```